# New ubuntu installation (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) constantly causing apps to crash

Tags: ubuntu, swap, crash, application, reinstall

After having a number of issues with applications crashing and worries about my hard drives being corrupt (I kept getting kernel panic signals at startup unless I started in recovery mode), I decided to just wipe everything and reinstall from a usb. After completing this step, I seemed to have a functional OS and proceeded to set up the rest of my applications and environments (conda, singularity, steam ect.).

After completing this step, everything seems to run as expected for about an hour, at which point applications begin to crash. After noticing this, I used the USB to entry "try Linux" setup so I could check and repair all disks/partitions. Doing this, showed there were no issues with any of my partitions.

After this did not work, I tried to see if the issue was due to the lack of swap space, as this seems to be a common problem after installation. So following a guide which creates a swap file, and increases the swap space to something larger, I still ran into the issue.

At this point I am not sure what the issue could be or how to resolve it. I am wondering if during installation I did not partition my hard drive correctly since I opted to install the new os on the second hard drive instead of the first (where my original installation was).

I do also know that the crashes are from an oom error following journalctl -u system-oomd, however even when I disable systemd-oomd the crashes still occur. I should also clarify that my machine has two hard drives, one of which is partitioned into a FAT (unmounted), Ext4 (unmounted), Swap (active), +freespace, while the second (which I used to create my installation is partitioned into FAT (mounted) and Ext4 (mounted at root). It seems like I am not correctly creating a swap (I was following https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/1177939#1177939), but I am not sure how to resolve. Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was that I had a horribly corrupted ram that needed to be replaced. I found this out after installing pcmemtest and running it overnight. At which point, I found that I had 40k+ memory errors, had it replaced, and stopped having these issues.